# DetailText LineBreakMode Not Working

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have my own custom element derived from StyledMultilineElement:

```
public class SubmenuElement : StyledMultilineElement
{

    public static UITableViewCellStyle DefaultCellStyle { get; set; }

    public static UITableViewCellAccessory DefaultCellAccessory { get; set; }
    public static UILineBreakMode DefaultDetailTextLineBreakMode { get; set; }

    public UILineBreakMode DetailTextLineBreakMode { get; set; }
    public int? DetailLines { get; set; }
    public bool? DetailTextResizesFontToFitWidth { get; set; }


    static SubmenuElement()
    {
        // Set the defaults
        DefaultCellStyle = UITableViewCellStyle.Default;
        DefaultCellAccessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
        DefaultDetailTextLineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation;
    }

    ...


    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell (tv);
        if (cell.DetailTextLabel != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.DetailTextLabel.Text))
        {
            if (DetailLines.HasValue)
                cell.DetailTextLabel.Lines = DetailLines.Value;
            cell.DetailTextLabel.LineBreakMode = DetailTextLineBreakMode;
            if (DetailTextResizesFontToFitWidth.HasValue)
                cell.DetailTextLabel.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = DetailTextResizesFontToFitWidth.Value;
        }
        return cell;
    }

}
```

It seems that setting the LineBreakMode for DetailText has no effect.

```
public class PeopleView
{

    ....



    void CreateUI()
    {
        var root = new RootElement(Header)
        {
            GroupAndSortResults(people, CurrentState.PeopleDirectoryOptions.GroupAndSort)
                .Select (g => new Section(g.Key)
                {
                    g.Select<PeopleListItem, SubmenuElement> (p => new SubmenuElement(
                        GetName (p),
                        p.TypeGradeSchool, 
                        () => GoToPersonProfile(p.ID),
                        null,
                        UITableViewCellAccessory.None,
                        UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle
                    )
                {
                    ImageUri = PersonAvatarImage.GetAvatar (p.ID),
                    OnImageLoaded = WhenImageLoaded,
                    DetailTextLineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.MiddleTruncation,
                    DetailTextResizesFontToFitWidth = true,
                    DetailLines = 0
                }).ToArray ()
                }).ToArray()
        };
        this.Root = root;
        this.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems = new UIBarButtonItem[] 
        {
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Organize, new EventHandler(WhenOrganizerTapped)),
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh, new EventHandler(WhenRefreshTapped))
        };
    }

}
```

Any ideas on why the truncation for detail lines doesn't work? Everything else works properly. My default is tail truncation but for this specific view I wanted middle truncation. No truncation styles work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out fast... It will truncate when the DetailLines property is set to 1. Truncation or text resizing using `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` doesn't work unless that lines number is set to 1.

If there is a similar question to this one on SO, I will delete this question, unless it is upvoted (it helps someone else out).

Comment: upvoted this answer; also works great when you're enabling editing mode with the swipe that will reveal the red "delete" button.